# Laravel 4 login doesnt work

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

If i try to login i just get this url:

http://xx.xx.xx.xx/game/public/?_token=4kXP1sYlLIizUUMyMWluK6jSEOacDikXafUSVrIF&username=dieter&password=azerty

Im probably doing something stupid.. Here is my code:

controller:

```
public function postSignin() {
        if (Auth::attempt(array('username'=>Input::get('username'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))) {
            return Redirect::to('users/dashboard')
                ->with('message', 'You are logged in');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('index')
                ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrent.')
                ->withInput();
        }
    }
```

Login form:

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'users/signin')) }}
                    {{ Form::text('username', null, array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => 'Username')) }}
                    {{ Form::password('password', null, array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => 'Password')) }}

                    {{ Form::submit('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
                    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Routes:

```
<?php
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

It's like it is ignoring the 'url' in the login form. If i change it to something else it just responds the same way.

I've bene googling all day for this, so please help. ^^

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your routes?

Comment: Can you show us your routes files and the error?

Comment: added routes.

There is no error, the page reloads, and i get this link in the brower: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/game/public/?_token=4kXP1sYlLIizUUMyMWluK6jSEOacDikXafUSVrIF&username=dieter&password=azerty

Comment: It seems your using GET request instead of POST. Try `Route::post('users/signin', array('as' => 'users.signin', 'uses' => 'UsersController@postSignin'));` instead of `Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Thanks tho
But, the code i have right now, did work in my previous "project"... I'm so confused ^^ I think the form just doesn't redirect me to user/signin for some reason.

Comment: Type `php arsitan routes` and post all of them here.

Comment: Is the log file empty? Is your debug config attribute to true? Has some routing the 'index' alias?

Comment: UsersController@getRegister
UsersController@postCreate
UsersController@postSignin  
UsersController@missingMethod 
HomeController@getIndex  
HomeController@getIndex  
HomeController@missingMethod

Comment: There are no new logs, and yes debug config is set to true.

Comment: Here you can try to login for yourself:
http://69.28.95.50/game/public/index.php/index

Maybe you will know whats wrong then

login: demo
pass: azerty

Comment: Try this in the Form definition `{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'users/signin') ) }}` in spite of `url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a form without `action` attribute, and your submit button sends you to the same page. Try to change the Form declaration as this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'users/signin') ) }}
```

I hope this works fine.